# Prove or counterexample: $f(cn) \in \theta (f(n))$

Tags: algorithms, proof-writing, asymptotics

Prove or provide a counterexample: For every positive constant c, and every function f from nonnegative ints into nonnegative reals, $$f(cn) \in \theta (f(n))$$.

At first, I thought this was obvious, then me and a friend ended up with radically different answers.  My first thought was that a constant times a number would do nothing to the theta of the function, but according to him, it would make $f(cn) \in \theta (f(n^2))$ , but im not buying that.  Then theres my sister ( 3 years younger) who says were both idoits! Please help!

Comment: hint: for a counterexample, you would need $f(cn)$ to grow so much faster than $f(n)$ that there's _no_ constant $K$ such that it's less than or equal to $Kf(n)$.  What functions can you think of that are particularly fast-growing?

Answer (score 4):

HINT: In your list of standard ‘sizes’ you probably have $\Theta(1)$, $\Theta(\lg n)$, $\Theta(n^k)$ for different values of $k$, $\Theta(2^n)$, $\Theta(n!)$, $\Theta(n^n)$, and maybe a few more. Experiment with these functions, especially some of the faster-growing functions, examining how the ratio $\frac{f(cn)}{f(n)}$ behaves as $n\to\infty$. The slower-growing functions and the exponential are especially easy to check.

Comment: Really, it's worth experimenting with _all_ of the functions on this list, as the relationships between $f(cn)$ and $f(n)$ for most of them crop up with a remarkable regularity.  For some you may need to do a little research to get comparable rates of growth.  Another comparison worth doing, once you've done this, is looking at $(cn)!$ vs. $(n!)^c$; this is a generalization of the 'central binomial coefficient' (which is the case $c=2$).

Comment: @Steven: I agree; in fact, I’ve modified the answer to that effect.

Comment: This is what I looking for, thank you.

Comment: @Jason: You’re welcome.

Comment: @Jason: No, it really doesn’t. Is $2^{2n}\in\Theta(2^n)$? Don’t make any guesses based on the similarity of form; work it out just as you would any problem of that kind.